# is there anyway to automatically create a mesh for an armature

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, edit-mode

i have some animation files that needs to be modified, when i import them in blender, the animation file doesn't have a mesh attached to it and that makes modifying super hard.
is there anyway to automatically add a default mesh or something to these armatures ?if not, 
then what is best way to modify an animated armature without a mesh
[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an add-on, called Skinify.
[image]

Comment: rotation of my bones are not how they should be, as you can see in the picture i attached to my questions some one bones are horizontal while they should be vertical and vice versa so that doesn't let the addon work how it supposed to work. but anyway your answer was great, thank you very much.